# How to only show PHP errors to myself?

Tags: php

I've seen a few methods for hiding php errors using php.ini or by adding `php_flag display_errors off` to .htaccess, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make it so only I can see php errors (useful for debugging obviously), but anyone else will be redirected to some boilerplate error page. I have a few scripts on my site that use my forum to authenticate me as an admin and kick everyone else out, so maybe it's possible using the same method?

If this isn't possible, I guess I'll go with the .htaccess method since I don't have access to php.ini. Is adding `php_flag display_errors off` to .htaccess a good way to go for this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd really recommend using log to file instead. Enabling debugging on a live server is dangerous as it can expose sensitive data. I know you are looking to restrict it to authorized users... but I still wouldn't risk making a mistake. Plus, if you log to file you can capture everybody's errors.

Comment: +1, Agree with konforce. Too much can go wrong if the wrong error gets shown to a user. A log file relies on a separate authentication system (the OS) to make sure you're the only one who can see it, which is what you want, because what if the thing that's broken is your authentication code?

Comment: @konforce - thanks for the response. Do you have a link or something that explains how to log to file? I'm sort of a novice and don't know how to do that :)

Comment: I've supplied an answer that covers logging to a file. It should cover enough of the basics to get you started.

Answer (score 3):

While displaying errors on screen is great for development (as you see them right away), they should not be enabled for production servers because you may accidentally expose sensitive information (e.g., database passwords) to unauthorized users.

The useful INI options are:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set('error_log', '/path/to/my/php.log');
ini_set('log_errors', 'On');      // log to file (yes)
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off'); // log to screen (no)
```

With that, all errors will be logged to the specified file. No errors will be seen on the screen.

Make sure the web server user is able to write to that file. You may have to create it and `chmod` / `chown` it accordingly before running your script.

On private development servers, you could disable the log file and display directly to screen. When developing, I would also get in the habit of displaying `E_NOTICE` errors as well. (Just use `E_ALL` as the value.) And if your scripts are well written, you can then continue to log them while in production too. An `E_NOTICE` is good for catching typos in variable names or array indices.

Note that all of those options can also be set in the `php.ini` or `.htaccess` files. But if you use `.htaccess` you cannot use the `E_*` constants; instead, you must hardcode the integer representation. (i.e., In a `.htaccess` file, you use whatever the results of `<?php echo E_ALL ?>` show as the value, or whatever you wish to log.)

In fact, I would recommend setting them in the `php.ini` if at all possible. Otherwise, if there's a script parsing error (or the `ini_set` gets skipped for some reason), you may not get the errors logging properly, etc.

On a Linux box you can always do a `tail -f /path/to/my/php.log` from a shell to monitor the log in realtime.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with konforce, this is possible by setting the error reporting at runtime with the error_reporting() function. If you insist on doing that, put it in the same block of code that you mentioned for determining you are the admin, so that you don't have the decision made in different places.

Answer (score 1):

Since your code already knows you are an admin you can use a logic like this:

```
if($_SESSION['isadmin']==1){
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('log_errors', 1); 
}
```

The admins will see errors but the other users will not see the errors.

Comment: This is a good partial solution. However, it will not catch syntax errors. I have found that, when developing in PHP, syntax errors are a huge portion of errors, things like missing semicolons or unclosed quotes or parentheses. Good syntax highlighting in your editor can reduce, but not completely eliminate this problem. In many cases, having a separate testing server with error reporting enabled in the config file can actually save you time over a solution like this, because it makes it easier to debug the syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can check against the users IP, and if it matches yours, you can show errors.
Something like this:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'your.ip.address'){
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
} else {
    error_reporting(0);
}
```

If you don't know you external IP, just google "what is my ip" or similar.

Base case scenario is obviously having a dev-server.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a users system, set the codes so it recognize you when you log in, and show errors. So, it will only show errors when it's you who is logged in.